# How to Track Individual Users in Google Analytics by using next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, next.js, google-analytics

Track individual users in Google Analytics and get a singular view of your customer journeys.
If your application or website has a login authentication system, then it is possible to track users in Google Analytics using the next js.
I wanted to report that the user can visit my website or take the user ID or email, connected with my database.
I can also ask if we can test the tracking ID on localhost or vertical link

using the stack of next js. and I try the code which is using the react. ga plugin they gave the changing route query

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: actually i my testing on local host .using the script of tracking Id , after giving the testing on my webiste . the google analtyics not giving the real time result